# Mixing incremental with synchronised backups

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I have a root directory on my laptop (source) which I want to backup to an external drive (destination).

In this folder there is data which I want to keep in sync with the destination (e.g. using `rsync --delete`, so when files from source are deleted, they will also be deleted from the destination).

However, there is also some data which I want to ”permanently” store (add-only), meaning that if I delete this data (or part of it) from the source, it will not be deleted from the destination.

What would be a **maintainable** way of solving this problem?

Comment: That would be very easy with SyncBack Pro.  You can Sync, Mirror and Move. A profile for each type of operation. I have used this for a very long time.